# Not Able to Find ESRI.ArcGIS.Client For ArcGIS Runtime .Net SDK on WPF Samples

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am trying to re-produce the demonstrated sample at this [**link**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/samples/index.html#//02q2000000s4000000) but I am not finding the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Client` any where in .Net Runtime SDK references or even from "Add ArcGIS Reference" wizard from Arc Object tools but still not seeing any `ESRI.ArcGIS.Client`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-wpf/index.html) was a predecessor to the current version of the Runtime that includes support for Windows platforms, which is the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/).  The Runtime for .NET includes support for WPF in addition to other platforms.  Although the API surface (namespaces, names, etc) differs, most of the functionality that was present in the Runtime for WPF is available in the Runtime for .NET, in addition to many new capabilities that have since been added.  The main class used in the example you've linked, LocalGeoprocessingService, is available in the Runtime for .NET, and the API reference for it can be found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_LocalServices_LocalGeoprocessingService.htm).

Note that the ArcGIS Runtime is for building stand-alone applications that incorporate GIS capabilities.  If you're looking to extend the functionality of ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, then the Runtime is the wrong product.  The "Add ArcGIS Reference" dialog in your question is for adding references to ArcObjects libraries, which are primarily used for building extensions for ArcMap or other ArcGIS Desktop programs.  The ArcGIS Runtime libraries are separate from those.